# Can't find some nodes using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I want to get all div from a [page](https://www.booking.com/hotel/rs/belgrade-art.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAsowQFCFmh5YXR0LXJlZ2VuY3ktYmVsZ3JhZGVIM1gEaG-IAQGYATG4AQbIAQ_YAQPoAQH4AQOSAgF5qAID;sid=d1c09a70f53e232bbe3e62c702624ae4;all_sr_blocks=24682601_89068719_0_41_0;checkin=2017-12-04;checkout=2017-12-05;dest_id=3399;dest_type=region;dist=0;hapos=13;highlighted_blocks=24682601_89068719_0_41_0;hpos=13;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srepoch=1511463409;srfid=f49abacf3f03ffc23b5d8ea9c5da08dfa007d667X13;srpvid=dd8785372b1300bf;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl) :

I use two method :
Method 1 : (from parent)

```
int ahc = documentz0.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='facilitiesChecklist ']/div").Count;
foreach (HtmlNode link in documentz0.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='facilitiesChecklist ']/div"))
{

}
```

or Method 2 : (with full search)

```
int ahc = documentz0.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'facilitiesChecklistSection')]").Count;
foreach (HtmlNode link in documentz0.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'facilitiesChecklistSection')]"))
{

}
```

With two method ,there is 17 div in page with this property, but it select just 14 of them .

[image]

Closing tag has not problem.

Comment: Please share the output of both methods and how many are they returning with .Count

Comment: The problem is that 3 div sent via ajax.